# Displaying user name with the help of a method in C#

Tags: c#

Cant't figure out what I am doing wrong,want to display user name in console through a method in the same class,missing a minor syntax please have a look and guide me.

```
 public class Program
  {
   string name;
   public void GetName()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter ur name");
       name = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Name is",name);
       Console.ReadLine();

   }

    static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.GetName();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for the function you are calling. Put your cursor over it and press F1 it will likey have examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the format string try:

```
public class Program
  {
   string name;
   public void GetName()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter ur name");
       name = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Name is {0}",name);
       Console.ReadLine();

   }

    static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.GetName();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You I missed the {0}.

Comment: You bet! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this

```
Console.Writeline("name is:" + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Name is : " + name);
```